# Performing simple network call to retreive JSON in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity, javascript

I have looked at the network documentation for Unity and most examples seem to be related to networking your game for multiplayer. I am just looking to grab a JSON response from an API for dynamically generating a menu.

Are there some good examples for doing just simple network calls to get a response from a web server?

Comment: Please don't cross-post. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216127

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You go through the WWW class.

http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/WWW.html

You can do a GET or POST through that, and get the .text from the result when it finishes downloading.  There are several C# JSON decoders that you can use instead of parsing the result yourself.

Comment: That was perfect, every time I searched for network help it only came back with information about the Network class. Thanks.